# Why doesn't FileChannel append to end of file?

Tags: java, file-io, nio

I am trying to download a few different files from a REST API using Java.

So far, I am getting the files, but the content won't append to the end of an output file.

I changed the `FileOutputStream` constructor from `new FileOutputStream(path)` to `new FileOutputStream(path, true)` but somehow it does not work.

Can somebody please provide pointers to what I am missing?

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetXML {

 
    // This Method Is Used To Download A Sample File From The Url
    private static void downloadFileFromUrlUsingNio() {

        String filePath ="config/sample.txt";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the NO which you want to parse: ");       
        
        
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
        
        String sampleUrl = "e.g.comSearch?NO=" + in.nextLine();
    
 
        URL urlObj = null;
        ReadableByteChannel rbcObj = null;
        FileOutputStream fOutStream  = null;
 
        // Checking If The File Exists At The Specified Location Or Not
        Path filePathObj = Paths.get(filePath);
        boolean fileExists = Files.exists(filePathObj);
        if(fileExists) {
            try {
                urlObj = new URL(sampleUrl);
                rbcObj = Channels.newChannel(urlObj.openStream());
                
                fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
 
                fOutStream.getChannel().transferFrom(rbcObj, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
                
                System.out.println("! File Successfully Downloaded From The Url !");
            } catch (IOException ioExObj) {
                System.out.println("Problem Occured While Downloading The File= " + ioExObj.getMessage());              
            } finally {
                try {
                    if(fOutStream != null){
                        fOutStream.close();
                        System.out.println("fOutStream closed");
                    }
                    if(rbcObj != null) {
                        rbcObj.close();
                        System.out.println("rbcObj closed");
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioExObj) {
                    System.out.println("Problem Occured While Closing The Object= " + ioExObj.getMessage());
                }               
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File Not Present! Please Check!");
        }
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println("Scanner Closed");
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        downloadFileFromUrlUsingNio();
    }
}
```

Comment: What gets printed when you run this?

Comment: @OneCricketeer "! File Successfully Downloaded From The Url !", fOutStream closed, rbcObj closed, Scanner Closed when i have 1 input string

Comment: 1) You don't close the channel obtained from `fOutStream`. --- 2) You should check the return value of `transferFrom(...)`. --- 3) You should use *try-with-resources*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written:

```java
fOutStream.getChannel().transferFrom(rbcObj, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

The second parameter, 0, specifies that data should be transferred to the file *at position zero.* The position is absolute, and it doesn't matter that you opened the file for append, because you are ignoring the current channel position.

Note [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom-java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel-long-long-) that states,

> position - The ***position within the file*** at which the transfer is to begin; must be non-negative

Your code is an unconventional approach to a common task. As such, it's hard for readers to comprehend, and, when you encounter mistakes, hard for you to get help. Since `URL` only offers `InputStream` support, stick with streams, and avoid channels.

Comment: Thank you for the Info, I somehow overlooked this part when i was researching.